# Please give an example of a ring that does NOT have a multiplicative identity but contains a subring that does have an identity..

Tags: ring-theory

I cannot think of an example of such a ring.  For that matter, other than the even integers I cannot even think of an example of a ring without an identity.

Comment: Have you looked at $\Bbb Z \times 2\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did your text prove such a ring exists?

Comment: @Unit. OK    The ring theory text I am reading did NOT prove such a ring exists.  It proved that IF such a ring exists then the identity of the subring is a zero divisor of the ring.  Thanks for your question.  I will edit the post.

Comment: *I cannot think of an example of a ring without an identity* Any nontrivial ideal of a domain (ring without nonzero zero divisors) is an example, as is any nonzero nil ideal of a ring (an ideal whose elements are nilpotent.)

Comment: @rschwieb.  OK Thanks.  So would you  agree that if we let Z[x] be the the ring of all polynomials with integer coefficients then Z[x] is an integral domain.  Then if I is a subset of Z[x] that contains only the polynomials that are divisible by 1 + x^2 then I is an ideal of Z[x] and I has no identity.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer $\Bbb Z[x]$ is certainly a domain, and no nontrivial ideal will have an identity. Yes, you could use the multiples of $1+x^2$, or even the multiples of $x$ for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most immediate example is $\Bbb Z \times 2\Bbb Z$. The subring consisting of $\{(n, 0)\mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$ has an obvious identity.

Many unital rings have subrings without identity. Proper (left or right) ideals are good examples.

For any element $x$ that is idempotent (i.e. $x^2 = x$), the subring $\{nx \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$ will have $x$ as an identity. If $x$ isn't an identity for the whole ring, then you've got an example there.

Comment: One such example of that I find entertaining is the ring of even integers mod 20 and the subring of multiples of 4, for which (the idempotent) 16 is the identity.